# Sitecore publish items outside of Home

Tags: sitecore, publishing

I create a Sitecore item outside of the "Home" location. When I publish the item it does not appear in the Web database. It looks like it's getting skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The location of your item in the content tree does not have any impact on whether the item is published or not. It doesn't matter if your item is under `Home` node or not.

There might be multiple reasons why your item is skipped while publishing:

1. The item has no language versions in the language you selected while publishing.
2. Parent (or other ancestor) of the item is not published, doesn't have any version in the language you're publishing.
3. There are some publishing restriction set for the item or one of its ancestors.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I checked all you said.  The item is in English, it is the root item and at the same level as Home (Under Content).  No publishing restrictions, but it still does not work.  The items is off the Sample Item template.  Still it does not get shown in the Web database.

Comment: is the item is a workflow? Is it in final workflow state or maybe in `Draft` or some other state?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the workflow and ensure it is in the proper state. Normally the sample template has workflow set in its standard values.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to enable tracing to get an idea the reason why the item was not published.

Please find `<publishItem>` pipeline in /App_Config/Sitecore.config file and change `<traceToLog>` node value to "true" for the UpdateStatistics processor. When you publish item again additional tracing messages will be added Sitecore log file. There should be a reason for skipping the item. Hope this will help.

Note: do not forget to return the value to "false" once the problem is fixed. Tracing is a little bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the "Never publish" checkbox is ticked